# How to get row index in JXLS 2.3.0

Tags: jxls

I can use varStatus property in jxls 1.X to get the row index while using foreach to traverse a list, But jxls 2.3.0 does not support this, how can output the row index in EXCEL with jxls 2.3.0 ?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand in current version of JXLS rowStatus doesn't work.

You may use one of these options:

1) You can add row index in index-attribute in your data before place in to JXLS and print in row-template as ${row.index}

2) You can use excel formula like =ROW()-ROW(HEADER_CELL). So if your table-headers end on A4, so in template you need write $[ROW()-ROW(A4)]

Answer (score 2):

Since JXLS 2.7.0, you can specify `varIndex="foo"` in your `jx:each` comment, then refer to it as `${foo}`

Ref: https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/173/how-can-i-get-index-in-jx-each

Answer (score 1):

For JXLS example :`jx:each(items="yourList", var="currentValue", lastCell="N7")`
You can using `${yourList.indexOf(currentValue)}` to get index.

Answer (score 0):

use ROW()-ROW(HEADER_CELL) works,